# Tried to install oh-my-posh but it tells me that "the term is not recognized as..."

Tags: windows, powershell, oh-my-posh

So I tried installing oh-my-posh for windows with

`Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser`

and typed

`Get-PoshThemes`

to see the available themes which I downloaded.
But I got this message

```
Get-PoshThemes : The term 'Get-PoshThemes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PoshThemes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-PoshThemes:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: After instaling, shouldn't you also need to `Import-Module oh-my-posh`  and add that command in your `$Profile` ?? See [this](https://zimmergren.net/making-windows-terminal-look-awesome-with-oh-my-posh/)

Comment: I'm having the same issue... @Theo `Import-Module oh-my-posh` didn't fix it for me. It could be an issue with the latest version-- I'm using 6.42.3. When I get a sec, I'll try the latest commit on the oh-my-posh GitHub repo.

Comment: The old solution is deprecated, Try this: https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/migrating

Answer (score 14):

## Solution

*(Note: I'm running PowerShell 7.1 LTS)*

### First, install a Nerd Font:

*[skip if you've already done so]*

**Instructions for installing a Nerd Font:**

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/custom-prompt-setup#install-a-nerd-font

---

### Then, install `oh-my-posh`:

**1. Install: `posh-git` `oh-my-posh`:**

```sh
   # This first step isn't included in the Microsoft Docs page:
   Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
   
   # ...though this one is:
   Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser
```

**2. ...follow the rest of the instructions here:**

> https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh2#installation

**3. ...finally, try the command again:**

```sh
   # Set the prompt theme (defaults to 'agnoster' for me)
   # ! Note: You have to do this step first (or it still won't work)
   Set-PoshPrompt

   # List the available themes (should work now)
   # ! Note: this will attempt to render a bunch of graphics in your shell
   Get-PoshThemes
   
   # ! Note: use the -List option to avoid a bunch of graphics in your shell
   # This will list the paths to the themes (in plaintext):
   Get-PoshThemes -List
```

---

**Optional**

To avoid manually entering `Set-PoshPrompt`, include the command in your PowerShell `$PROFILE`:

```sh
    # ...e.g. to use the included 'zash' theme:
    Set-PoshPrompt zash
```

...you should see your PowerShell prompt change when you open a start shell instance (i.e. new PowerShell tab or window).

---

### Closing thoughts (side-note)

Before I got it to work, I originally followed the instructions here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/custom-prompt-setup#install-a-nerd-font

...no mention of the `posh-git` module or the `Set-PoshPrompt` command (as of 12/30/2021).

Comment: Hi, I followed first Microstoft guide than yours (and what is in GitHub) but doesn't work for me. When trying to run Set-Prompt I just get an error: The term 'Set-Prompt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Any tips how to deal with that?

Comment: @GKroch By `Set-Prompt`, do you mean `Set-PoshPrompt`? Apologies, I had a typo in one part of my answer (now fixed).

Answer (score 2):

Try `refreshenv`. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Form the [documentation](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/windows#default-themes) install the default theme first using:

```
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH\jandedobbeleer.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression
```

Then you can use `Get-PoshThemes`

Answer (score 0):

I following with docs from [ohmyposh](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/migrating) and it working with me

Comment: ... what exactly from it did you follow? Are you referring to specific part or the whole thing? see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: Please provide proper solution to the question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34582770)

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround from the oh-my-posh faq.  In this case, the profile has foreign characters in it, and utf8 characters need to be piped to invoke-expression.  The oh-my-posh functions are unpacked this way.  https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/faq/#powershell-the-term-oh-my-poshexe-is-not-recognized-as-a-name-of-a-cmdlet

```
$previousOutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8
try {
    oh-my-posh.exe init pwsh --config ~/custom.omp.json | Invoke-Expression
} finally {
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $previousOutputEncoding
}
```

Error message:

```
# (@(& 'C:/Users/Börke/AppData/Local/Programs/oh-my-posh/bin/oh-my-posh.exe' init pwsh --config='C:\WINDOWS\system32\custom.omp.json' --print) -join "`n") | Invoke-Expression

&: The term 'C:/Users/B├╢rke/AppData/Local/Programs/oh-my-posh/bin/oh-
my-posh.exe' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or executable program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Note that oh-my-posh is no longer installed as a powershell module, but via winget.

Answer (score -1):

I kept getting the cmdlet not found error even after following the guide by Robbie. For some reason a fresh install did not fix it for me but an update did:

```
Update-Module oh-my-posh
```

Comment: oh-my-posh no longer has a module, so this will no longer work.

Answer (score -1):

You can start your vs code by admin permissions and it will be fixed.
I'm using oh-my-posh version 14.29.1

Comment: This is a workaround and not a safe one.  If you make a mistake or your profile is compromised, there's signficantly less protection from 'bad things' happening.  The oh-my-posh installation instructions work, if you follow them.